# How to end ldap transaction with ApplicationExtendedRequest request in golang

Tags: go

I am new the ldap with golang, I am able to create transaction with ApplicationExtendedRequest but unable to end transaction with ApplicationExtendedRequest it is alway throwing "Failed to decode request" error this is happening as I try to include attributes in the request, please help me with some sample code for ending transaction operation.